# write_dta not working in R

Tags: r, r-haven

When I run stackQuestion.R in RStudio containing the following code:

```
library(haven)
write_dta(data.frame(a=1), "test.dta")
```

it works fine.

When I run

```
RScript --vanilla stackQuestion.R
```

from the Mac Terminal I get the error

> Fehler in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>     Writing failure: Unable to write data.
>   Ruft auf: write_dta -> write_dta_ -> .Call

**Update:**

Now, also the first code does not work anymore. I always get the error:

> Fehler in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>     Writing failure: Unable to write data.

Exorting via "foreign" works fine (so there are no issues concering writing rights).

```
library(foreign)
write.dta(data.frame(a=1), "test.dta")
```

I am really at a loss here and any hints are highly appreciated!

OS: macOS 10.12.2 (16C67)
RStudio: 1.0.136
R: 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)

Comment: This does work for me (on Windows). Can you try with an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: Perhaps it is writing to a folder without write permissions...? What OS is this?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: macOS 10.12.2 (16C67). No I tried it in my Documents folder.

Comment: Try specifying a path where you are 100% sure you have write access. Alternatively, you could also add `print(getwd())` to see where working directory is.

Comment: @takje: Absolute paths do not work either

Comment: @RomanLuštrik This prints "/Users/ruedigerziege/Documents".  sudo does not work either.

Comment: Your example works for me on Unbuntu, either with or without `--vanilla`.